# Wordpress button click event

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I have one page with some URL, in that page, I have one button. I want to redirect that page to another URL after clicking that button. Is there any way to do it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Please try something and get back to us when you get stuck.

Comment: I have tried redirect plug in, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just need a link not a redirect. Redirects are for catching the page before page load and redirecting away to a different page. A click:

```
<a href="http://example.com/"><button>Click Me!</button></a>
```

or if for some reason you need jquery:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  window.location.replace('http://example.com/');
});
```